# DrawerNavigator inside TabNavigator inside StackNavigator in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, slidingdrawer

I have a login page and after logging user in there is a TabNavigator screen, after clicking one of the TabNavigator icons DrawerNavigator menu should open.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav-home.png')} style={{height:25,width:25}}/>,
      header: null
    }
  },
  Store: {
    screen: Store,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Store',
      tabBarIcon: <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav-store.png')} style={{height:25,width:25}}/>,
      header: null
    },
  },
  Other: {
    screen: DrawerNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav-profile.png')} style={{height:25,width:25}}/>,
      header: null
    },
  }

},{
initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
  Profile: {screen: Profile},
  Search: {screen: Search},
})



export const Root = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen: Login},
  Tabs: {screen: Tabs},
},
  {
  initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
  }
)
```

This code gives me an error:

[image]

When user clicks **Other** menu-like screen should slide in from the left which will contain **Profile** **Search** and *Logout*(Like in Slack app) and when user clicks for example **Profile** screen they will be redirected to that page. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You just move "const DrawerNav" to above "const Tabs".
After that it will work